# How to find specific elements in XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, youtube-api, elementtree

I'm trying to parse XML string which I get from youtube video feeds, using `Python 3.3.1`. Here is the code:

```
import re
import sys
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree

def get_video_id(video_url):
    return re.search(r'watch\?v=.*', video_url).group(0)[8:]

def get_video_feed(video_url):
    video_feed = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + get_video_id(video_url)
    return urllib.request.urlopen(video_feed).read()

def get_media_info(video_url):
    content = get_video_feed(video_url)
    content = str(content, 'ascii')
    media = {}
    e = element_tree.XML(content);

    print ( "CONTENT: \n" + content )

    print ( "\n\nELEMENTS : \n")
    for i in list(e):
        print (i) 

    media['title'] = e.findall('title')   //NOTE THIS!
    return media


def main():
    video_url = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=q5sOLzEerwA' 

    print ( get_media_info(video_url) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've no idea why the `for` loop in `get_media_info()` prints elements as

```
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title' at 0x0000000002BF7D18>
```

instead of this:

```
<Element 'title' at 0x0000000002BF7D18>
```

Frankly, I don't care what it prints. All I care is that I want to pass `'title'` to `findall()` and expect a list of element(s) as returned value. But it returns empty list, even though there is one element with name `title` in the xml.

So I tried this:

```
media['title'] = e.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title')
```

And it did return a list of one element. I'm sure this is not the way to do it, and I feel I'm missing something.

How to fix this?

---

This is the output of the above code:

CONTENT:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/q5sOLzEerwA</id>
  <published>2011-12-01T18:18:36.000Z</published>
  <updated>2013-05-07T03:20:04.000Z</updated>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
  <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='Music' label='Music'/>
  <title type='text'>Kala Bazaar - Khoya Khoya Chand Khula Aasman - Mohd Rafi.flv</title>
  <content type='text'>tanhayi me akele me khoya khoya chand.........</content>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5sOLzEerwA&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
  <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/q5sOLzEerwA/responses'/>
  <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/q5sOLzEerwA/related'/>
  <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=q5sOLzEerwA'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/q5sOLzEerwA'/>
  <author>
    <name>a1a2a3a4a786</name>
    <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/a1a2a3a4a786</uri>
  </author>
  <gd:comments>
    <gd:feedLink rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/q5sOLzEerwA/comments' countHint='6'/>
  </gd:comments>
  <media:group>
    <media:category label='Music' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Music</media:category>
    <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/q5sOLzEerwA?version=3&amp;f=videos&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='293' yt:format='5'/>
    <media:content url='rtsp://v6.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkArx4xLw6bqxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='293' yt:format='1'/>
    <media:content url='rtsp://v6.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkArx4xLw6bqxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='293' yt:format='6'/>
    <media:description type='plain'>tanhayi me akele me khoya khoya chand.........</media:description>
    <media:keywords/>
    <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5sOLzEerwA&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
    <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/q5sOLzEerwA/0.jpg' height='360' width='480' time='00:02:26.500'/>
    <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/q5sOLzEerwA/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:13.250'/>
    <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/q5sOLzEerwA/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:02:26.500'/>
    <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/q5sOLzEerwA/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:03:39.750'/>
    <media:title type='plain'>Kala Bazaar - Khoya Khoya Chand Khula Aasman - Mohd Rafi.flv</media:title>
    <yt:duration seconds='293'/>
  </media:group>
  <gd:rating average='4.733333' max='5' min='1' numRaters='30' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall'/>
  <yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='8140'/>
</entry>
```

ELEMENTS :

```
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id' at 0x0000000002BF79F8>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published' at 0x0000000002BF7B88>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}updated' at 0x0000000002BF7A48>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}category' at 0x0000000002BF7C78>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}category' at 0x0000000002BF7CC8>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title' at 0x0000000002BF7D18>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content' at 0x0000000002BF7D68>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link' at 0x0000000002BF7DB8>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link' at 0x0000000002BF7E08>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link' at 0x0000000002BF7E58>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link' at 0x0000000002BF7EA8>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link' at 0x0000000002BF7EF8>
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}author' at 0x0000000002BF7F48>
<Element '{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}comments' at 0x0000000002C0B0E8>
<Element '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}group' at 0x0000000002C0B1D8>
<Element '{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}rating' at 0x0000000002C0B778>
<Element '{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}statistics' at 0x0000000002C0B7C8>
{'title': []}
```

Answer (score 14):

The namespace of an XML document is significant.  ElementTree requires tags to be fully qualified to find the right element.  Here's an example of three elements with the same tag in different namespaces:

```
data = '''\
<root xmlns="xyz" xmlns:name="abc">
  <object name="one" />
  <name:object name="two" />
  <object xmlns="def" name="three" />
</root>
'''
```

Here's the elements that ElementTree sees:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
>>> tree = et.fromstring(data)
>>> print(tree.findall('.//*'))
>>> et.dump(tree)
[<Element '{xyz}object' at 0x0000000003B07BD8>,
 <Element '{abc}object' at 0x0000000003B07C28>,
 <Element '{def}object' at 0x0000000003B07C78>]
```

So you have it right.  Given the default namespace definition of:

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' ...
```

To access the 'title' tag, which uses the default namespace:

```
media['title'] = e.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title')
```

to access the 'media:group' tag, refer to the media namespace definition:

```
<entry ... xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' ...
```

And use:

```
e.findall('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}group')
```

Note the different ways a namespace can be specified:

```
<root xmlns="xyz" xmlns:name="abc">   # default namespace and
                                      # 'abc' namespace with id 'name'.
  <object name="one" />               # Uses default namespace 'xyz'.
  <name:object name="two" />          # uses 'abc' namespace (specified by id).
  <object xmlns="def" name="three" /> # change the default namespace to 'def'.
</root>
```

To read a specific tag from a specific namespace:

```
>>> print(tree.find('{abc}object').attrib['name'])
'two'
```

Note the namespace IDs are just shortcuts.  Here's what happens when you dump the parsed XML tree.  ElementTree doesn't bother to save the original namespace IDs and generates its own in the format `ns#`:

```
>>> et.dump(tree)
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="xyz" xmlns:ns1="abc" xmlns:ns2="def">
  <ns0:object name="one" />
  <ns1:object name="two" />
  <ns2:object name="three" />
</ns0:root>
```

If you want specific shortcuts defined, use `register_namespace':

```
>>> et.register_namespace('','xyz') # default namespace
>>> et.register_namespace('name','abc')
>>> et.register_namespace('custom','def')
>>> et.dump(tree)
<root xmlns="xyz" xmlns:custom="def" xmlns:name="abc">
  <object name="one" />
  <name:object name="two" />
  <custom:object name="three" />
</root>
```

Comment: I tried `element_tree.register_namespace('', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')` and  then `media['title'] = e.findall('title')`. It still returns empty list. Can we make it work somehow without passing `namespace` to `findall()`?

Comment: No, `register_namespace` is only for output. If you use `ElementTree`, you have to pass the fully-qualified name.  Just write a helper function to tack it on. You might look at the third-party `lxml`.  It has an ElementTree-like interface and may have the ability you want.  I'm not as familiar with it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I have tried the following way using `xml.dom.minidom`, Just in case it helps you anyway.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import re
import urllib

def get_video_id(video_url):
    return re.search(r'watch\?v=.*', video_url).group(0)[8:]

def get_video_feed(video_url):
    video_feed = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + get_video_id(video_url)
    print video_feed
    return urllib.urlopen(video_feed).read()

def get_media_info(video_url):
    content = get_video_feed(video_url)
    dom = parseString(content)
    media = {}

    media['title'] = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    return media

def main():
    video_url = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=q5sOLzEerwA' 

    print ( get_media_info(video_url) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is so much easier! Though I'm assuming this way is also less specific, however if you know your input you can be sure that it'll work.